# Fix the torn window screens

Tags: windows, screens

I have two windows with torn screens that need to be fixed. I looked up on this forum for similar problems and solutions. I found some but not exactly like mine.

Anyway, can someone take a look at the pictures here and offer some suggestions as to what might be the best way to replace the broken screens.

[image]

[image]

You might notice the windows are pretty old and I cannot tell who is the manufacturer and what is the brand.

Comment: You'll probably find that the fabric is held in by a rubber spline on the outside of the sash. You don't need to replace the whole thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are standard screens easy to repair. Pull the rubber / plastic retainer material out of the groove, the old screen fabric will fall out if it did not pull out when removing the retainer.

Get a roll of the type of screen fabric you want to use. There are different colors and materials. I like to place the frame on the floor for large ones and the kitchen table for smaller. Verify that the frame is still square by measuring corner to corner diagonally. Lay the fabric on top of the frame. They make roller tools to push in the retainer but I always cut the screen with these so I use a carpenter's pencil to push the retainer in.

If caution is used you will end up with a very nice tight fit. Use a razor knife to trim the excess on the outside edge for a good finished job.

I find the expanded poly retainer a real pain and I usually tear it during removal if you have this type of retainer you may want to pick up a roll when you get the screen it is inexpensive. Hope that helps.

Comment: I've just been doing a series of screens after one was torn badly - several others were also in need of replacement and there's more screen on the roll. My "spline tool of choice" is a fairly dull, fairly big screwdriver - never seen much point in the rollers. Be sure to have a little overhang on the screen, and pay attention to getting the first edge in straight (pull out the spline and go again if need be.) The screen directions suggest new spline, but my old (and it is OLD) spline was still flexible and works fine.